# Azure DevOps - Environment agent - yaml deploy to environment group

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I got a CI pipeline `Stuiter.Next-CI` which need to trigger the CD when completed based on a branch. (that doesn't work yet)

The only problem that I have is that I can't push to all agents in the environment. What I read in the documentation is that you can push to an entire environment group. I got 2 IIS servers in the `Stuiter-Next - Release Candidate` group.

- IIS18
- IIS19

The only problem is that I need to spicify in the environment to what server I want to deploy towards. Else it won't run on the agent but on an Azure Build agent in the cloud so it won't deploy the application.

What I read in the documentation is that you just define the group name and you deploy to all servers in that environment.

```yaml
jobs:
- deployment: DeployNextRc
  displayName: 'Deploy Next-RC'
  environment:
    name: 'Stuiter-Next - Release Candidate'
```

But to make it work (only on one agent) is to specify the agent.

```yaml
    name: 'Stuiter-Next - Release Candidate.IIS18'
```

Is there a way to deploy towards the entire group of agents that are registerd in the environment?

Entire yaml:

```yaml
# The CD pipeline is triggered by the CI pipeline if it's of the configured branch
# we don't need to trigger this by it self because it won't have the artifacts available yet
trigger: 
- none

# Trigger this pipeline when it's CI equivalent has completed succesfully (only if triggered on master, release/* or develop)
resources:        # types: pipelines | builds | repositories | containers | packages
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: buildPipeline  # identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables
    source: Stuiter.Next-CI  # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
    trigger:     # triggers are not enabled by default unless you add trigger section to the resource
      branches:  # branch conditions to filter the events, optional; Defaults to all branches.
        include: 
          - master
          - release/*
          - hotfix/*
          - develop
        exclude:
          - feature/*
          - bug/*
          - sprint/*

# The process of the deployment
jobs:
- deployment: DeployNextRc
  displayName: 'Deploy Next-RC'
  environment:
    name: 'Stuiter-Next - Release Candidate.IIS18'
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
  # Force that we only use a windows pool
  #pool: server
  #pool:
  #  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  # Variable set for the Release candidate pipeline
  variables:
    websiteDirectory: 'E:\Websites\'
    artifactDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    websiteName: 'Stuiter-RC'
    appPool: 'Stuiter-RC'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        # Get the version out of the Source branch name
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'Get version'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              $version = "$(Build.SourceBranchName).$(Build.BuildId)"
              Write-Host "$version"
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=stuiterVersion;isOutput=true]$version"
            name: stuiterVersion

        # Create the directory with the version
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'Create website folder if non existing'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
                [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory("$(websiteDirectory)\$(stuiterVersion.version)") | Out-Null
```

Comment: can't understand, do you have many servers in one environment?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes. In this case I got 2 servers in this environment. This is for QA. For production I got 9 servers to deploy to.

Comment: ok, and you want to deploy to all the server? what is the issue?

Comment: Well if I only target the environment, it won't run on the environment but on a hosted agent of Azure. It won't do any work on the agents. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: share here your full yaml and you Environments page.